# When is Tw(C) {ω}-filtered?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

I am interested in categories $\mathsf{C}$ for which coends commute with $\omega$-chain limits. That is, given a chain of profunctors $P_n \colon \mathsf{C}^{op} \times \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ with natural transformations $P_0 \gets P_1 \gets \dots$, the following canonical map is an isomorphism.

$$\int^X\lim_n P_n(X,X) \to \lim_n\int^X P_n(X,X)$$

From a paper by [Adamek, Borceux, Lack, Rosicky](http://maths.mq.edu.au/%7Eslack/papers/acc.html), it seems that the condition I am looking for is that $\mathsf{Tw(C)}$, the twisted arrow category, is $\{\omega\}$-filtered.

What are the $\mathsf{C}$ for which $\mathsf{Tw(C)}$ is $\omega$-filtered? Less ambitiously, what are conditions I can ask on $\mathsf{C}$ to prove that $\mathsf{Tw(C)}$ is $\omega$-filtered? How would one go about proving this, say, in the case $\mathsf{C} = \mathsf{Set}$?

---

My first attempt was to say that, if $\mathsf{C}$ has all weak $\omega$-chain limits then, in $\mathsf{Tw(C)}$, every $\omega$-chain has connected cocones. But this condition only seems to imply commutation of limits and colimits if $\{\omega\}$ is a so-called "sound" doctrine (see again [Adamek, Borceux, Lack, Rosicky](http://maths.mq.edu.au/%7Eslack/papers/acc.html)), and doctrines containing infinite things seem to be generally not "sound" (the doctrine of infinite products, for instance). Is the doctrine containing just an $\omega$-chain sound?

---

Comment: For every $\alpha\ge\omega$, the doctrine of categories with less than $\alpha$ objects is sound, so in general you have doctrines of infinite things that are sound; the doctrine of pullbacks is not sound, so you have a doctrine of finite things which is not sound. Also, careful: $\omega$-filtered is $\omega\textsf{-LIM}$-filtered in ABLR, which is a different thing than $\{\omega\}$-filtered.

Comment: how can there be a functor $\omega \to \varnothing$ in the first place? (I suspect the answer is "indeed", yet I find this strange) (comment vanished?)

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted my initial comment. I think the ultimate conclusion is correct, though: the doctrine of $\omega^{op}$-indexed limits is not sound. For instance, the span category $S = (\bullet \leftarrow \bullet \to \bullet)$ has the property that every functor $\omega \to S$ has a connected category of cocones; nonetheless, pushouts do not commute with $\omega^{op}$-indexed limits in $Set$.

Comment: This is way easier to believe :)